# 加速度センサーを用いて速度計を作成していますが、正しい速度が得られません。

Tags: c, arduino

**聞きたいこと**
現在、加速度センサーから速度を計算するプログラムを作成していますが、速度の異常がなかなか解消されません。この問題をどのように解決すればよいでしょうか。

**目標**
加速度センサーの値から+-1km程度の誤差の速度を求めたいです。

**状況**
速度から速度を計算するプログラムを作成していますが、速度の異常がなかなか解消されません。具体的にはセンサーを加速させて一旦停止した際にセンサーを動かしていないにも関わらず速度の値が上昇し続けている状態です。

**これまでに試したこと**
誤差を修正するために、キャリブレーションを追加しました。それにより、初期のプログラムに比べ誤差が軽減されましたが、まだ改善されていない部分があります。具体的には、センサーを加速させて一旦停止した際にセンサーを動かしていないにも関わらず速度の値が上昇し続けている状態です。

**センサー**
MPU-9250

**コード**

```
#include "Wire.h"
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"


int16_t ax, ay, az;
long ave =0;

float calculated_velocity = 0;  //合計速度
float current_velocity = 0;     //加速度*処理時間

unsigned long time = 0;


MPU6050 accelgyro;


void setup(){
   Wire.begin();
   Serial.begin(115200);

   Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
   accelgyro.initialize();//センサーを初期化
   accelgyro.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_16);

   Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
   Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   time = micros();//プログラムの動作開始からの時間

   for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
      accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
      ave += ax;
   }
   ave /= 500;//誤差の平均
   Serial.println("Calibration is complete.");
}


void loop(){
   unsigned long now = micros();
   float duration = (now - time)/1e6;//処理にかかった時間
   time = now;

   current_velocity = 0;
   //姿勢検出シールドのセンサーの値をチェックし、各変数に記録する
   accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);

   current_velocity = (ax-ave) * duration / 204; //(x軸の加速度-誤差)*処理にかかった時間/204
   calculated_velocity += current_velocity;

   Serial.println(calculated_velocity*3.6,3); //3.6はm/s→km/h、","の後ろの数は桁数
```

Comment: 実際に得られたセンサーの値と計算結果を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: 普通にキャリブレーション行うなら 前後・左右は 0で, 上下は 1g の加速度になるよう設定するはず(個体差などあるから)。センサーを移動させその後 静止させた時に数値が狂うのならセンサーが可怪しいかも (まずはそこからでは？) / 加速度から速度得るには微積分で算出するけど両方記さないと何が可怪しいか分からない(センサーが可怪しいか演算が間違ってるか)

Answer (score -1):

> 加速度センサーの値から+-1km程度の誤差の速度を求めたいです。

原理的に見て、それは無理なはなしです。
全く誤差がないという状況では、計算上速度を得ることができるでしょうが、
残念ながら、現実はそういうわけには行きません。

Comment: では、どのくらいの誤差の範囲内であれば速度を求めることができるでしょうか？

Comment: あなたのお使いの加速度センサの誤差はどれぐらいでしょうか それがわかれば、そこから算出されるであろう速度の誤差が、計算で算出できます。同様に、あなたが要求している速度の誤差に納める場合に、どれだけの精度の加速度センサが必要か、が、計算できます。まずはそれをやってみよう。